# What is and where to see in transaction in Etherscan the fields result.contractAddress and result.confirmations in API?

Tags: transactions, addresses, receipts, explorer-api

When I download data from a contract using API there are 2 fields that i cannot understand in which part of transaction in Etherscan are these numbers and maybe give me the definition of those fields:

Result.contractAddress /
Result.confirmations

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please provide more details on the api used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the api's details, here is what it looks like (tbc with further details on the api), with screenshots from a random transaction on etherscan :

- Result.confirmations: number of block that have been mined since the transaction has been included (those blocks are following, decreasing the likelihood of a reorg/having the tx excluded) [image: confirmations]
- Result.contractAddress: the contract that has been interacted with (the "to" field of the tx, if it was a contract interaction) [image]

Comment: Hi, I have this transaction from API:

result.hash: 0xac56535744628da665cbb20a0b18a603ea3da1275d955ddc959080024b138d44
result.contractAddress: 0
result.confirmations: 96797
result.blockNumber: 12810189

result.hash: 0x785efdee101c00598fdd788584b1148f580ab9e94996109f73643c298852564c
result.contractAddress: 0
result.confirmations: 96791
result.blockNumber: 12810195

I cannot find those numbers like you mentioned in bscscan. where to find them?

Comment: I used Bscscan API to get Normal transaction.

Comment: Just search for your hash in bscscan and you will see those infos (the confirmation will keep growing up, since each new mined block is one extra confirmation) - the first one : https://bscscan.com/tx/0xac56535744628da665cbb20a0b18a603ea3da1275d955ddc959080024b138d44

Comment: Ty for your help :)